# Stripe API: Module not found: Can't resolve '@stripe/react-stripe.js'

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Do I have a simple typo? Do I need to install anything else? I'm getting the following error message:

"Module not found: Can't resolve '@stripe/react-stripe.js'"

I have also npm installed: @stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js

Appreciate any help figuring this out!

Below are screenshots for reference:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide code in text using code blocks instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import ... from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
```

You are importing it in the wrong way. `@stripe/react-stripe.js` is not correct. Just replace `.` with `-`, it should work then.

As you can see in the its document. You need to import its component from `@stripe/react-stripe-js`

[stripe-js correct import statement](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider)

Answer (score 2):

Stripe API ReactJS Error

```
“Module not found: Can’t resolve ‘@stripe/react-stripe.js’”
npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.11.0

‘@stripe/react-stripe-js’ or ‘@react-stripe-js’
```

When I read the official Stripe docs, everything looked simple. However, I stuck at the first step for an hour.

The issue was a

```
Error: module not found: can’t resolve ‘@stripe/react-stripe-js’
```

It is a very simple error that occurs when we miss modules. But I definitely installed and followed the official manual like the below picture. It was very weird so I started to install another one but didn’t work.

So how do you fix it?

First, open your ” package.json” and take a look at

if your package is okay, it supposed to look like this below

```
@stripe/react-stripe-js”: “1.4.1”,

“@stripe/stripe-js”: “1.15.0”,
```

the Left side should be the package name and the right side is a version of the package. But when I opened up

```
“@stripe/stripe-js”:“github:stripe/stripe-js”

@stripe/react-stripe-js”:“github:stripe/stripe-js”
```

So I reinstalled it like this, added a specific version of the package instead of copying it from Strip docs.

Try like this (Answers)

```
npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.1.2

npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js@1.11.0
```

And It solved easily. I am not sure why this issue happened. If I find the reasons, I will add them or if you know the reasons please let me know.